# ASP.NET MVC 3 Unobtrusive Validation - Before Validate Event?

Tags: jquery, asp.net, asp.net-mvc-3

Using ASP.NET MVC3's unobtrusive validation feature how can I run some JavaScript before validation runs? Jquery's submit handler runs after validation for obvious reasons. I can hook into a click on the submit button but that doesn't seem very elegant. Any suggestions?

**EDIT**

It appears my above statement is incorrect. As was pointed out below the submit handler does run before validation. Unfortunately that does not solve my problem.

My revised question:

I need to manipulate a form value after form submission but before jQuery validation. If I change the value after submission using jQuery's submit handler then jQuery validates the original value not the new value.

Comment: I solved this issue. I had the submit handler within a jQuery document ready handler. Once I removed it I was able to manipulate the form submission before submission as desired.

Comment: For anyone else confused by the comment above: you need to move the submit handler out of the document ready handler and put it right below the form.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The submit handler doesn't run after validation. It runs before. Try it:

```
$('form').submit(function () {
    alert('validation hasn\'t run yet at this point => see there is no red color over your form input fields yet');

    if ($(this).valid()) {
        alert('the form is valid');
    } else {
        alert('the form is not valid');
    }
});
```

---

UPDATE:

After the revised question I am still unable to reproduce the issue. Here's my model:

```
public class MyModel
{
    [Required]
    public string Name { get; set; }
}
```

and here's my view:

```
@model MyModel

<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>
<script src="@Url.Content("~/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js")" type="text/javascript"></script>           

@using (Html.BeginForm(null, null, FormMethod.Post, new { }))
{
    @Html.EditorFor(x => x.Name)
    @Html.ValidationMessageFor(x => x.Name)
    <input type="submit" value="OK" />
}

<script type="text/javascript">
    $('form').submit(function () {
        $('#Name').val('some value');
    });
</script>
```

Now if I leave the Name field blank and submit the form, the new value is being properly assigned and the form is successfully submitted to the server without any errors. If I remove the `$('#Name').val('some value');` line that assigns a new value and try to submit the form with an empty field client side validation triggers and the form is not submitted.

Comment: the validator (if he configured it to run onsubmit) would execute on submit. If I'm not wrong, the code you pasted would execute before or later depending the attach order to the submit event. And as a side note the order would be guaranteed as long he uses jquery to bind the events (as you example does).

Comment: Thanks for the response Darin. Please see my revised question.

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure if it will be a solution but you could have a look to **IClientValidatable** Interface http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.web.mvc.iclientvalidatable(v=vs.98).aspx

Here's example (quite old) but should work in the current release:
ASP.NET MVC: Adding client-side validation to ValidatePasswordLengthAttribute in ASP.NET MVC 3 Preview http://blogs.msdn.com/b/stuartleeks/archive/2010/07/28/asp-net-mvc-adding-client-side-validation-to-validatepasswordlengthattribute-in-asp-net-mvc-3-preview-1.aspx