# JQuery-validate submitHandler not working on MVC 4

Tags: jquery, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, jquery-validate, unobtrusive-validation

I'm working on an MVC4 view model and trying to implement unobtrusive validation with JQuery. For testing purposes, I have implemented a couple of custom validation rules and they work perfectly when I copy the generated MVC code (see below) to a JSFiddle, but it does not work at all within the MVC project.

I know Javascript is working in the MVC view model because the alert('lol') does indeed pop up everytime the page loads. It is just the submit handler and the validation rules that have no effect.

As a note, the following are set to true on Web.config:

```
<add key="ClientValidationEnabled" value="true" />
<add key="UnobtrusiveJavaScriptEnabled" value="true" />
```

Also, these are the included scripts:

```
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-1.7.1.js"></script>    
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.unobtrusive-ajax.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery.validate.unobtrusive.js"></script>
<script src="/Scripts/jquery-ui-1.8.20.js"></script> 



<form action="/Edit/Edit" id="SubmitForm" method="post" name="SubmitForm">                <fieldset>
                    <legend>Details</legend>
                    <table>
                        <tr><th>Site</th><th>Account</th><th>Metric Name</th><th>Value</th></tr>


<tr><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field siteId must be a number." data-val-required="The siteId field is required." id="siteId" name="siteId" type="hidden" value="60" /></tr>
<tr><input data-val="true" data-val-number="The field accountId must be a number." data-val-required="The accountId field is required." id="accountId" name="accountId" type="hidden" value="14633" /></tr>
<tr><input data-val="true" data-val-date="The field monthYear must be a date." data-val-required="The monthYear field is required." id="monthYear" name="monthYear" type="hidden" value="2013-10-01 12:00:00 AM" /></tr>
<tr><input id="accountName" name="accountName" type="hidden" value="Company1" /></tr>
<tr><input id="siteName" name="siteName" type="hidden" value="Auckland, New Zealand" /></tr>

<tr>
<td>Auckland, New Zealand</td>
<td>FONTERRA</td>
<td>Calls Offered</td>
<td><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-is="your high value needs to be greater than your low value." data-val-is-dependentproperty="handled" data-val-is-operator="GreaterThan" data-val-is-passonnull="False" data-val-number="The field offered must be a number." data-val-required="The offered field is required." id="offered" name="offered" type="text" value="8052.00" /></td>
    <td><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="offered" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Auckland, New Zealand</td>
<td>Company 1</td>
<td>Agent Incoming Calls Handled</td>
<td><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field handled must be a number." id="handled" name="handled" type="text" value="7882.00" /></td>
<td><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="handled" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></td>
</tr>

<tr>
<td>Auckland, New Zealand</td>
<td>Company 1</td>
<td>Calls Transferred</td>
<td><input class="text-box single-line" data-val="true" data-val-number="The field transferred must be a number." id="transferred" name="transferred" type="text" value="38.00" /></td>
<td><span class="field-validation-valid" data-valmsg-for="transferred" data-valmsg-replace="true"></span></td>
</tr>

  (...)
  (...)
  (...)

        <script>
            $(document).ready(function () {
                alert("lol");
                $.validator.addMethod('lessThan', function (value, element, params) {
                    var field_1 = $('input[name="' + params[0] + '"]').val();
                    return parseInt(value) < parseInt(field_1);
                }, "lessThan");

                $("#SubmitForm").validate({
                    errorElement: "span",
                    rules: {
                        offered: {
                            required: true,
                            digits: true,
                            lessThan: ['handled']
                        },
                        handled: {
                            required: true,
                            digits: true
                        }
                    },
                    messages: {
                        offered: "Offered has to be >= handled",
                        handled: "Enter number of offered calls"
                    },
                    submitHandler: function (form) { // for demo
                        alert('valid form');
                        return false;
                    }
                });

            });

</script>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The answer to this question: [ASP.NET MVC 3 Unobtrusive Validation - Before Validate Event?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/6391946/asp-net-mvc-3-unobtrusive-validation-before-validate-event) answers the title of your question. So you can use the submit event as follows:

```
$('#SubmitForm').submit(function () {
    if ($(this).valid()) {
        alert('the form is valid');
        //you can add return false here if you want to perfom manual validation and cancel the submit
    } else {
        alert('the form is not valid');
    }
});
```

For the custom unobtrusive validation rule, you will also need to ensure that your input element has the attribute `data-val-lessThan="some validation message"` and you will need an unobtrusive adapter as well. Add something like this after your `$.validator.addMethod` :

```
$.validator.unobtrusive.adapters.add("lessThan", function (options) {
   options.messages["lessThan"] = options.message;
});
```